# How to process proto extension?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Given the following:

```
extend google.protobuf.FileOptions {
    Server server = 50621;
}

message Server {
    // Java classname
    string name = 1;
}
```

And a `.proto file` that uses the extension:

```
option (com.netflix.proto.options.server).name = "TestData";
```

I see the extension itself can be accessed with `file->extension(com::netflix::proto::options::server.number())`.
How would a C++ proto plugin get the value of `(com.netflix.proto.options.server).name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get to the extension is through the `options()` method:

```
file->options().GetExtension(com::netflix::proto::options::server).name()
```